# How to access a connector / Data Base from the initial/instantiation Form/Page?

Tags: groovy, ldap, instantiation, connector, bonita

How to access a connector / Data Base from the initial/instantiation Form/Page?

Hi every body, any help will be appreciated.
I try to access using the API Rest, but the method need the activyty/task id or the instance flow id.
This is because the connector stores its result in a proces/local/Busines data model or Variables,
but in the initial form I don't have an
instance of the flow/task/activity and I can't access to the variable that stores the value.
I need to use the connector to access data base and to the Ldap
to get some values to show in the initial form before instantiating the process.
Is there any way to call a Groovy Script from initial Form?, if there is,
I can access from that script to the data base, and save this value into a form variable, to show it in the form I think.
P.S.: I use Bonita 7.2
thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, you probably need to use a REST Api extensions. Basically, you can create a new REST Endpoint using Groovy script. There is a documentation available here: http://documentation.bonitasoft.com/rest-api-extensions-808

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you have a chicken and egg problem.
Can you instantiate the process with minimal data, then use a connector out to populate the BDM with the connector data, and then make the first step of your process the "initial" form?  At that point you then have the case, taskid, etc.

If the data is not task/case specific, you can access the BDM data via the REST API and a custom query - i.e. you're not just limited to the API's that require the case/task/instance, etc.  However, you may need to get clever with how you isolate that record.  For example, I have some global parameters that I keep in in the BDM, and access them within my form by requesting the first record in that table via the rest API:

I created a variable called "globals" of type "External API" with the following REST call that retrieves the record with persistenceId=1:

```
../API/bdm/businessData/com.company.model.GlobalParameters/1
```